# Libgdx - Check if a key is being held down?

Tags: java, html, cross-platform, libgdx

I'm using the java libgdx game library and im curious if I can tell if a key is being HELD, not pressed and let go.

I need to know this because I'm going to play a shorter mp3 file if it is just pressed and a longer one if it is held.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can easily check they either via `Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.XXX)` or by implementing an [`InputProcessor`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/InputProcessor.html).

```
public class MyInputProcessor implements InputProcessor {

    public boolean keyPressed;

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        if (keycode == Input.Keys.XXX) {
            keyPressed = true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        if (keycode == Input.Keys.XXX) {
            keyPressed = false;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And using it like this:

```
MyInputProcessor processor = new MyInputProcessor();
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(processor);

...

if (processor.keyPressed) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

You can read more about that [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Event-handling).

Comment: This does not work, what if i want to hook up two keys for hold down events? Do i need to make a `boolean` for every possible key? Using the static `Gdx.input.isKeyPressed` method works for holding but there should be a easy way to make this work using the `Interface`

Comment: There's nothing more advanced in the libgdx API for key combinations. You gotta do that yourself.